# Using NLog to output to one of two log files

Tags: c#, nlog

I have a single-threaded .NET Winforms application. I am using a static NLog logger to log errors using this syntax:

```
MyLogger.Log.Error("Error occurred...");
```

In accordance with my one NLog.config-defined target and one NLog.config-defined rule, that log-error output always is written to a file called "errors.txt". Sometimes I want an error to be written to "errors2.txt" instead. How would I do that without creating another static logger instance?

Comment: What is the problem with creating another static logger instance if that brings you to your goal?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a medium to ask question (even stupid once) and learn from each other: This would result in duplicated code would have been more than enough for me to understand you problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use filters in the config or pass the filename to the logger call.

Note: These examples are using `.WithProperty` (on the NLog `Logger`), introduced in NLog 4.6.3

#### Filters

Use filters in the logger rules, we use the LogFinal so we need only the rules once (not needed for the 2nd logger rule)

See [Filtering log messages on the NLog wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages)

```xml
<rules>
  <logger name="*" writeTo="file-error1">
    <filters defaultAction='LogFinal'>
      <when condition="${event-properties:target} == 'error2'" action="Ignore" />
    </filters>
  </logger> 
  <logger name="*" writeTo="file-error2">
  </logger> 
</rules>
```

Logger call:

```cs
MyLogger.Log.Error("Error occurred..."); // writes to file-error1 target
MyLogger.Log.WithProperty("target", "error2").Error("Error occurred..."); // writes to file-error2 target
```

#### Pass file name

Pass the file name in as property. Maybe you could set a default property in the static `Log` method.

See also [Event properties documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer)

```xml
<targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
        ....
        fileName="${basedir}/logs/{event-properties:filename}" 
        ...  />
</targets>
```

Logger call:

```cs
MyLogger.Log.WithProperty("filename", "error1.txt").Error("Error occurred...");
MyLogger.Log.WithProperty("filename", "error2.txt").Error("Error occurred...");
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching about .WithProperty and for offering the idea of passing the file name. Fantastic!